# How to get nested items from Firebase with order by

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I made a following structure in Firebase.

```
members //collection
 L authIds //documents
    L cars //collection
       L car0 
          L data0
              L create_date
          L data1
              L create_date
          L data2
              L create_date
       L car1
          L data0
              L create_date
```

In this case, I would like to order by create_date in only car0.
And moreover I'm using StreamBuilder.

Please tell me how to retrieve such a data.

Comment: Did you find the solution or still stuck inbetween?

Comment: I've been still stucking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Orders').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('Loading ...');
            }

            List<CustomWidget> comments = [];
            snapshot.data.documents.sort((a, b) => a['DecidedOptionList'][0].compareTo(b['DecidedOptionList'[1]]));
            snapshot.data.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
              comments.add(CustomWidget(id: doc.documentID,));
            });

            return ListView(
              children: comments,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, orderBy('cars') had already implemented. I would like to know how to order by create_date in nest.

Comment: could you edit your post to indicate which ones are documents which ones are field and so on?

Comment: try using the `sort` method on your `snapshot.data.documents` inside `builder` [https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/sort.html]

Comment: Hum. I don't get how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something like below:

```
     StreamBuilder(
         // get firestore collection snapshot here
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('members').document(authIds).collection('cars').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('Loading ...');
            }
          // sort the document data here
          snapshot.data.documents.sort((a, b) => a['create_date'].compareTo(b['create_date']));
          // print data here
              return new ListView.builder(
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 // item count of document data
                 itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,                   
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // current snapshot document
                  DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                         // print current data in a sorted manner
                         Expanded (child:Text(ds["create_date"]) ),
                      ],
                  );
                  }
               );
          }),
    );
```

As I haven't implemented the above code, you can fix it as per your need. :)

Comment: The following error happened `type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(DocumentSnapshot, DocumentSnapshot) => int' of 'compare'`

Comment: try like this: snapshot.data.documents.sort((a, b) => a['create_date'][0].compareTo(b['create_date'][0]));